# Prove that if both $a$ and $b$ divided by $n$ give remainder 1, then $ab$ divided by $n$ gives remainder 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here's is my approach:
$a=q_1n+1$
$b=q_2n+1$
$ab = q_1q_2n^2+q_1n+q_2n+1=(q_1q_2n+q_1+q_2)n+1$

I'm not sure if this is sufficient, and if so, whether there's a better proof.

Comment: This is indeed correct. I do not know a "better" proof involving less calculation. But there might be.

Comment: Modular arithmetic is a good and powerful tool.  Yes, if $a\equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $b\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $ab\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is good. One could also use modular arithmetic to say that $a\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod n$ gives $ab\equiv 1\cdot 1\equiv 1\pmod n$, however I like your approach better because it uses the actual remainder as in the division algorithm, rather than using the relationship between remainders and modular arithmetic.

Comment: This  is a comment not answer

Comment: @Leox I provide verification of the OP's proof (i.e. I address the fact that the proof is sufficient), and I offer another proof at their request (the idea of a better proof is maybe subjective). What else should an answer to this question entail?

Answer (score 1):

$(ab-1)=\underbrace{(a-1)b}_\text{divisible by n}+\underbrace{(b-1)}_\text{divisible by n}$

*But it is not much different from your proof : 
rewrite it $(a-1)(b-1)+(a-1)+(b-1)$ and replace $(a-1)$ by $q_1n$ and same for $b$.*